# Anugar JS - After Item Push To Object Array not refreshing in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have push a new element to my object array and i want in the view to reflect it but it doesn´t work.

can someone help please?

its the first time i using angular js.

My Code

**JS**

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);
App.controller('TestCTRL', function ($scope) {

    $scope.addToList = function() {
        $scope.listitems = [];
        var f = this.data.firstName;
        var l = this.data.lastName;
        var i = this.data.id;

        var newItem = new function() {
            this.firstName = f;
            this.lastName = l;
            this.id = i;
        }

        $scope.listitems = $scope.listitems.push({newItem});

        $scope.$apply();

    }



});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="TestCTRL">
     ....
.....
....

  <div ng-repeat="item in listitems">     
    <div>{{item.firstName}}</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do without assignment,

```
$scope.listitems = $scope.listitems.push({newItem});
```

to

```
$scope.listitems.push({newItem});
```

Comment: then you need to make a copy using angular.copy and push to that list

Comment: mhh. can you explain me how to do it please.. thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by overwritting?

Comment: Use angular.copy($scope.listitems.push(newItem)); It is going to make a shallow copy.

Comment: i do push the item into my array object and the ng-reapeat shows the item.. but if i push a second element, the push function not append, is overwrite the item before added

Comment: are you trying to add the same item?

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
$scope.listitems.push(newItem);
```

returns nothing, so assignment is unnecessary.